# Old passport that contained my B1/B2 was snipped in the corner

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas, passport-renewals

Immigration New Zealand returned my old passport cut in the corner all the way through which means my B1/B2 visa has also had the corner snipped off.

Is it still valid? Do I need to reapply or can it be reissued in my newly-issued New Zealand passport?

Comment: Is anything removed from the machine readable portion of the visa, or it otherwise could be considered damaged? If so, you need a new visa.

Answer (score 2):

[If your visa has been damaged in any way, you will need to reapply for a new visa at a U.S. Embassy or Consulate abroad.](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/general/frequently-asked-questions/about-visas-the-basics.html)

If the corner trim is the size I think it is some of the machine readable characters will have been lost. UK passports used to be cancelled by having corners cut off and from the corner typically more than a centimetre was removed (I have one with nearly an inch). Though the UK was good enough to cut only the covers.

Comment: It includes the machine readable part which is a bummer. I did just read that what Tump has done hasn't totally done away with the visa waiver program, so as a New Zealander I should be fine on my 2 week trip with out my B1/B2. Initially I thought that the Visa Waiver program had totally been scrapped but it looks like not -http://www.sbs.com.au/yourlanguage/hindi/en/article/2017/01/26/update-australian-tourists-wont-be-hit-trump-order

Comment: Nah havent visited any of those countries although I have tri nationality with UK and Venezuela, so as long as none of those countries piss Trump off I should be alright. Thanks for the info!

Comment: UK passports still are cancelled that way, mine within the last four months.  I was grateful they only cut the covers, since it means the B1/B2 visa in my old passport is still valid (and I have since used it, along with my new US-visa-less passport, to enter the US).